# Storing and retrieve images with google app engine in android?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I developed an android app with google app engine as a server.
Now I want to add photo sharing feature in my app, 
Google app engine provides Cloud Datastore/Cloud Storage for large data like images.

My question is that is **Cloud Datastore** an efficient way for storing and retrieving images or any other third party database is more efficient than Cloud data store/cloud storage.

Please guide me and give me your helpful suggestions.

Comment: Cloud datastore is not for storing files. Cloud Storage would be the solution.

Comment: @3371862 what is the BlobProperty for then?

Comment: mongoDb  or cloude storage which one is efficient or better option

Comment: @TimCastelijns You're right, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage is a better solution than a database for storing and serving images, and allows you to do things like [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) (serving content directly, securely).

Directly from the "[Choosing a Storage Option](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/)" page:

## [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/)

**Description:** A scalable, fully-managed, highly reliable, and cost-efficient object / blob store.

**Good for:**

- Images and videos
- Objects and blobs
- Unstructured data

Comment: thanks @Dan McGrath for answer ,can you give me some code refrence how to doing this in android